# How to fire a function when template is fully loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I use Angular UI in my project and I need to fire a function when template is fully loaded. I know there is ng-init directive but I don't want to use it.Is there any other way to fire function when page fully loaded?

Comment: use a directive. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have datePicker directive and it has ng-model, I need to get value from ng-model to use it.But it seems that that value that I get fromng-model is not valid because I retrieve it when directive is loads and the value is not stable.

Comment: Provide demo that reproduces problem. What datepicker are you using? Question should contain relevant code and the actual problem. what you are asking is an XY problem

Answer (score 1):

document.onLoad() & document.onReady() should work in your case